# SQLIte syntax error but I do not see one

Tags: java, android, sqlite

It was working before I changed a Integer Not Null to Integer on the scores table.

The error is "E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "(": syntax error"

And the statement in question is -

```
CREATE TABLE "runs" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "run_number" INTEGER NOT NULL, "total_time" REAL, "stroop_on" INTEGER NOT NULL, "successful" INTEGER NOT NULL, "successful_run_number" INTEGER NOT NULL, "training_run" INTEGER NOT NULL, "score_id" INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN_KEY (score_id) REFERENCES scores(_id));
```

UPDATE: turns out it was a silly mistake, just added a '_' in "Foreign Key"

Comment: All of the "("'s or just the ones in the foreign key statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove underscore from foreign key

Comment: That was it, don't know why I did that